# Unable to delete CloudWatch Events trigger in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am not able to edit nor delete the CloudWatch Events trigger in AWS Lambda.

[image]

I used the below command but it didn't work.

```
aws events delete-rule --name "startEC2"
```

Could anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Did it come back with an error?

Comment: No, I didn't get any error or output @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0):

Do check the IAM Role that you used in a lambda function. To remove cloudwatch event trigger, you have to delete the 'cloudwatch event' from your IAM Policy statement that is attached to IAM Role for this function.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can do from lambda console is assign/remove a cloudwatch event that will trigger the particular lambda function. If you want to delete the cloudwatch rule, why not go to the Cloudwatch Console itself???

Also, if you want to delete via CLI, make sure you got proper permissions to do so.

That command doesn't work in the following cases:

1. You aren't connected to the internet.
2. You don't have AWS CLI installed in your node.
3. You haven't properly configured your aws credentials/profile.
4. You haven't got enough permissions to do delete-event API call.

But above all, its unlikely to get no output at all, in any case.
Please do clarify your question properly.